# How to create a new custom field in an existing package in FLOW3

Tags: php, doctrine, typo3-flow

At present I create a package named "MyPackage". It dynamically generates a page name `CoffeeBean.php` in it ..

```
<?php
namespace MyPackage\Domain\Model;

/*                                                                        *
 * This script belongs to the FLOW3 package "MyPackage".                  *
 *                                                                        *
 *                                                                        */

use TYPO3\FLOW3\Annotations as FLOW3;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    class CoffeeBean
    { 
        protected $name;

        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }
    }
?>
```

I need to create one more field in it, named email. Can any one help me, I'm new to the FLOW3 concept.

Answer (score 0):

BY using the plug-in EXTENSION BUILDER we can able to create a new package in typo3.in flow3 we need to Alter the code using the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Just add the property $email (protected) and the set/getter in your CoffeeBean class, after that go to command line tools:

```
# flow doctrine:update
```

And Flow will automatically upgrade the database schema for you, with the proper configuration.